# How to Upgrade pyexpat.pyd?

Tags: python-3.x, dllimport

Python contains expat library in its DLLS directory. I am running `python3.7.4`.
I need to upgrade `pyexpat` version to `2.2.9`, but I do not want to upgrade python version. What should I do?